# Xamarin Studio 4.1.0.45 crash at start on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: c#, mono, crash, xamarin

I have installed latest Mono from official stable release and Xamarin Studio 4.1.0.45 on a Mac OS X 10.6.8.

My question is:
Why I can't run Xamarin Studio? (Xamarin Studio crashed)

Below is the crash output that is sent to Apple.

```
Process:         XamarinStudio [806]

Path:            /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/XamarinStudio
Identifier:      com.xamarin.monodevelop
Version:         4.1.0.45 (4.1.0.45)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [603]

Date/Time:       2013-07-14 18:22:13.539 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          67190 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           1
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID:                      0AC38D29-17B2-4E06-94D0-8859BF641070

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _strndup
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Binary Images:
0x1000 -     0x3ffc +com.xamarin.monodevelop 4.1.0.45 (4.1.0.45) <8241FFBF-049F-345B-9AD7-F3E02FC7005C> /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/XamarinStudio
0x200000 -   0x52cfea +libmonosgen-2.0.dylib ??? (???) <58EC5DCB-F0EA-3CDA-9EF4-1BDE800E0A41> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4163b  dyld 132.1 (???) <4CDE4F04-0DD6-224E-ACE5-3C06E169A801> /usr/lib/dyld
0x90003000 - 0x90046ff7  libGLU.dylib ??? (???) <6CC3CE6A-7024-C685-EADA-7F9DC27128E2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
0x90047000 - 0x90112fef  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices 359.2 (359.2) <7C16D9C8-6F41-5754-17F7-2659D9DD9579> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x901ba000 - 0x901edff7  com.apple.AE 496.5 (496.5) <BF9673D5-2419-7120-26A3-83D264C75222> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x90247000 - 0x90267fe7  libresolv.9.dylib 41.1.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8C2B5FA8-2469-21C7-D297-F95A0FFE5F19> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x90268000 - 0x9026dff7  com.apple.OpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <0603680A-A002-D294-DE83-0D028C6BE884> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
0x9026e000 - 0x90296ff7  libxslt.1.dylib 3.24.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <E761F29A-328B-29D9-3DF0-023F2C21E500> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x913ba000 - 0x9143afeb  com.apple.SearchKit 1.3.0 (1.3.0) <9E18AEA5-F4B4-8BE5-EEA9-818FC4F46FD9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
0x91594000 - 0x915a2fe7  libz.1.dylib 1.2.3 (compatibility 1.0.0) <33C1B260-ED05-945D-FC33-EF56EC791E2E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x915cd000 - 0x916cdfe7  libxml2.2.dylib 10.3.0 (compatibility 10.0.0) <BE7FCD73-03B5-25A4-FCA4-D4980F1488D6> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x916ce000 - 0x916d9ff7  libGL.dylib ??? (???) <3E34468F-E9A7-8EFB-FF66-5204BD5B4E21> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
0x916da000 - 0x916daff7  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <ABF97DA4-3BDF-6FFD-6239-B023CA1F7974> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x91ef6000 - 0x91f46fe7  libTIFF.dylib ??? (???) <AB182CEC-188A-F2BC-21E1-0059FD3B2598> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
0x91f4b000 - 0x91fa8ff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit 2.0 (???) <3DABAB9C-4949-F441-B077-0498F8E47A35> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x91fa9000 - 0x92041fe7  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.11 (6.5.11) <F36DB665-A88B-7F5B-6244-6A2E7FFFF668> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
0x92182000 - 0x921b3ff7  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <D18E2E76-DBF4-6930-039A-F66CA0D120B3> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
0x921c2000 - 0x921cfff7  com.apple.NetFS 3.2.2 (3.2.2) <DDC9C397-C35F-8D7A-BB24-3D1B42FA5FAB> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
0x921d0000 - 0x921d0ff7  com.apple.vecLib 3.6 (vecLib 3.6) <FF4DC8B6-0AB0-DEE8-ADA8-7B57645A1F36> /System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x92560000 - 0x925c1fe7  com.apple.CoreText 151.13 (???) <23F359DA-D845-5C50-4DF3-19E858CF2B2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
0x925c2000 - 0x9267afeb  libFontParser.dylib ??? (???) <D2D0C922-5ED1-3AE9-6F99-707C74DF3E62> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
0x926b0000 - 0x926cefe7  libPng.dylib ??? (???) <6C0B95D7-9634-E044-0B79-F1DD56961C33> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x92783000 - 0x92783ff7  com.apple.ApplicationServices 38 (38) <8012B504-3D83-BFBB-DA65-065E061CFE03> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
0x927bf000 - 0x928fcfe7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <423BDE4D-5082-B6CA-BB2C-E22A037235A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x928fd000 - 0x9294dff7  com.apple.framework.familycontrols 2.0.2 (2020) <596ADD85-79F5-A613-537B-F83B6E19013C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyControls.framework/Versions/A/FamilyControls
0x9294e000 - 0x92b11feb  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.6 (3.0.6) <AE641FAD-DF38-AE31-B45B-85AEE7AF3A45> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x9307f000 - 0x9311cfe3  com.apple.LaunchServices 362.3 (362.3) <15B47388-16C8-97DA-EEBB-1709E136169E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x93178000 - 0x9349cfef  com.apple.HIToolbox 1.6.5 (???) <21164164-41CE-61DE-C567-32E89755CB34> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
0x93567000 - 0x93577ff7  libsasl2.2.dylib 3.15.0 (compatibility 3.0.0) <C8744EA3-0AB7-CD03-E639-C4F2B910BE5D> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
0x93578000 - 0x93582ffb  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <7486003F-8FDB-BD6C-CB34-DE45315BD82C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
0x93583000 - 0x9361efe7  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 275.19 (???) <2E83B3E9-AF39-36FC-5D05-CC1E952098AB> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
0x93649000 - 0x93e38557  com.apple.CoreGraphics 1.545.0 (???) <1D9DC7A5-228B-42CB-7018-66F42C3A9BB3> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
0x93e44000 - 0x93e91feb  com.apple.DirectoryService.PasswordServerFramework 6.1 (6.1) <00A1A83B-0E7D-D0F4-A643-8C5675C2BB21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PasswordServer.framework/Versions/A/PasswordServer
0x93e92000 - 0x93f24fe7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore 6.3 (312.7) <7410D1B2-655D-68DA-D4B9-2C65747B6817> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
0x93f25000 - 0x94019ff7  libiconv.2.dylib 7.0.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <061ABF36-8BA9-79C1-6CE7-EC69A4998F51> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x94031000 - 0x9403dff7  libkxld.dylib ??? (???) <9A441C48-2D18-E716-5F38-CBEAE6A0BB3E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x94102000 - 0x9413cff7  libcups.2.dylib 2.8.0 (compatibility 2.0.0) <A6C207E3-7B42-926D-9C93-BE3F50B92496> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
0x94557000 - 0x948c2ff7  com.apple.QuartzCore 1.6.3 (227.37) <E323A5CC-499E-CA9E-9BC3-537231449CAA> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x94bbd000 - 0x94cc9fe7  libGLProgrammability.dylib ??? (???) <6167CEB0-D8D6-C4D9-DD74-49755ADB540F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x94cca000 - 0x94ce9ff7  com.apple.CoreVideo 1.6.2 (45.6) <EB53CAA4-5EE2-C356-A954-5775F7DDD493> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
0x94cea000 - 0x94cf0fe7  com.apple.CommerceCore 1.0 (9.1) <521D067B-3BDA-D04E-E1FA-CFA526C87EB5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CommerceCore.framework/Versions/A/CommerceCore
0x94cf1000 - 0x94cf4fe7  libmathCommon.A.dylib 315.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <1622A54F-1A98-2CBE-B6A4-2122981A500E> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
0x94d69000 - 0x94d7dffb  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework 3.10.35 (3.10.35) <57DD5458-4F24-DA7D-0927-C3321A65D743> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x94d7e000 - 0x94dc0ff7  libvDSP.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <8A4721DE-25C4-C8AA-EA90-9DA7812E3EBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x94dc1000 - 0x94e3bfff  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 3.2.6 (3.2.6) <156A532C-0B60-55B0-EE27-D02B82AA6217> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x94e3c000 - 0x94e46fe7  com.apple.audio.SoundManager 3.9.3 (3.9.3) <5F494955-7290-2D91-DA94-44B590191771> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonSound.framework/Versions/A/CarbonSound
0x94fc8000 - 0x950cafe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib 0.9.8 (compatibility 0.9.8) <316C3B25-6DCA-549A-7728-D5A038F654D8> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
0x951c7000 - 0x95349fe7  libicucore.A.dylib 40.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <60FF302E-5FAE-749B-BC70-0496DC2FBF2D> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x9534b000 - 0x95391ff7  libauto.dylib ??? (???) <29422A70-87CF-10E2-CE59-FEE1234CFAAE> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x95392000 - 0x95393ff7  com.apple.audio.units.AudioUnit 1.6.7 (1.6.7) <93EC71F1-4D4E-F456-8EFE-32E7EFD7A064> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x95504000 - 0x955defff  com.apple.DesktopServices 1.5.11 (1.5.11) <800F2040-9211-81A7-B438-7712BF51DEE3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x955df000 - 0x955edff7  com.apple.opengl 1.6.14 (1.6.14) <82622F67-E032-0BF6-A78D-50B346E8D0FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
0x955ee000 - 0x955f7ff7  com.apple.DiskArbitration 2.3 (2.3) <E9C40767-DA6A-6CCB-8B00-2D5706753000> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x955f8000 - 0x9561effb  com.apple.DictionaryServices 1.1.2 (1.1.2) <43E1D565-6E01-3681-F2E5-72AE4C3A097A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x95658000 - 0x9565cff7  libGIF.dylib ??? (???) <2251F789-B187-0837-6E38-A0E5C7C4FA3C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x956a2000 - 0x95f85ff7  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.8 (1038.36) <A353465E-CFC9-CB75-949D-786F6F7732F6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
0x95f86000 - 0x95fcaff3  com.apple.coreui 2 (114) <2234855E-3BED-717F-0BFA-D1A289ECDBDA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x96043000 - 0x960ebffb  com.apple.QD 3.36 (???) <FA2785A4-BB69-DCB4-3BA3-7C89A82CAB41> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
0x960fa000 - 0x9641aff3  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore 861.39 (861.39) <5C59805C-AF39-9010-B8B5-D673C9C38538> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x9641b000 - 0x965c2ff7  libSystem.B.dylib 125.2.11 (compatibility 1.0.0) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x965c3000 - 0x966f1fe7  com.apple.CoreData 102.1 (251) <87FE6861-F2D6-773D-ED45-345272E56463> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
0x96dec000 - 0x96decff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.6 (Accelerate 1.6) <3891A689-4F38-FACD-38B2-4BF937DE30CF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x96ded000 - 0x96dedff7  com.apple.CoreServices 44 (44) <51CFA89A-33DB-90ED-26A8-67D461718A4A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
0x96e2d000 - 0x96e9cff7  libvMisc.dylib 268.0.1 (compatibility 1.0.0) <595A5539-9F54-63E6-7AAC-C04E1574B050> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x96ee5000 - 0x96f92fe7  libobjc.A.dylib 227.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <9F8413A6-736D-37D9-8EB3-7986D4699957> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x96fe3000 - 0x9715efe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation 6.6.6 (550.44) <F88C95CD-1264-782D-A1F5-204739847E93> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x9716b000 - 0x97581ff7  libBLAS.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <C4FB303A-DB4D-F9E8-181C-129585E59603> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
0x97582000 - 0x97630ff3  com.apple.ink.framework 1.3.3 (107) <233A981E-A2F9-56FB-8BDE-C2DEC3F20784> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Ink.framework/Versions/A/Ink
0x97631000 - 0x97643ff7  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework 207.11 (207.11) <6FF4F2D6-B8CD-AE13-56CB-17437EE5B741> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
0x97644000 - 0x97648ff7  libGFXShared.dylib ??? (???) <09540618-2ED1-72C4-61CB-938B35927568> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
0x97f09000 - 0x97fb5fe7  com.apple.CFNetwork 454.12.4 (454.12.4) <DEDCD006-389F-967F-3405-EDF541F406D7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
0x97fb6000 - 0x98009ff7  com.apple.HIServices 1.8.3 (???) <1D3C4587-6318-C339-BD0F-1988F246BE2E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x9800a000 - 0x980eafe7  com.apple.vImage 4.1 (4.1) <D029C515-08E1-93A6-3705-DD062A3A672C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x980eb000 - 0x980eeff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <37F56237-4ABA-E5B5-968D-70FFE357E8E0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x9823e000 - 0x984affef  com.apple.Foundation 6.6.8 (751.63) <69B3441C-B196-F2AD-07F8-D8DD24E4CD8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
0x98a1d000 - 0x98a5aff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.8 (1.10.2) <50E4D49B-4F61-446F-1C21-1B2BA814713D> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x98a5b000 - 0x98a73ff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory 10.6 (10.6) <D1CF5881-0AF7-D164-4156-9E9067B7FA37> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
0x98a74000 - 0x98a96fef  com.apple.DirectoryService.Framework 3.6 (621.16) <5566E769-6459-78A7-DD2C-1D3068BD3932> /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
0x98d4d000 - 0x98d4dff7  liblangid.dylib ??? (???) <B99607FC-5646-32C8-2C16-AFB5EA9097C2> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x98d4e000 - 0x98fb4ff7  com.apple.security 6.1.2 (55002) <E88E133F-5FB3-446F-B753-2B8AD577B46A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x98fdc000 - 0x99000ff7  libJPEG.dylib ??? (???) <50E17B4D-63D6-24D3-702F-6A6E912A55EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x990a2000 - 0x990a3ff7  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent 1.1 (1) <2D970A9B-77E8-EDC0-BEC6-7580D78B2843> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
0x990a4000 - 0x99126ffb  SecurityFoundation ??? (???) <C4506287-1AE2-5380-675D-95B0291AA425> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
0x99127000 - 0x991e3fff  com.apple.ColorSync 4.6.8 (4.6.8) <920DD017-8B41-7334-E554-A85DB99EBD5A> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x99f6d000 - 0x9a026fe7  libsqlite3.dylib 9.6.0 (compatibility 9.0.0) <52438E77-55D1-C231-1936-76F1369518E4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x9a033000 - 0x9a09dfe7  libstdc++.6.dylib 7.9.0 (compatibility 7.0.0) <411D87F4-B7E1-44EB-F201-F8B4F9227213> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x9a0b9000 - 0x9a0cdfe7  libbsm.0.dylib ??? (???) <14CB053A-7C47-96DA-E415-0906BA1B78C9> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x9a18e000 - 0x9a192ff7  IOSurface ??? (???) <89D859B7-A26A-A5AB-8401-FC1E01AC7A60> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
0x9a36d000 - 0x9a38efe7  com.apple.opencl 12.3.6 (12.3.6) <B4104B80-1CB3-191C-AFD3-697843C6BCFF> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x9a38f000 - 0x9a7c4ff7  libLAPACK.dylib 219.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <5E2D2283-57DE-9A49-1DB0-CD027FEFA6C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x9ab7c000 - 0x9ab7eff7  libRadiance.dylib ??? (???) <090420B3-CB65-9F7B-5349-D42F2F9693B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x9ab7f000 - 0x9abc3fe7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.3 (507.15) <74F05E64-2A68-BA10-CCD4-128D164E5A0F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x9abc4000 - 0x9abd5ff7  com.apple.LangAnalysis 1.6.6 (1.6.6) <3036AD83-4F1D-1028-54EE-54165E562650> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0xbad00000 - 0xbad01fe7  libLatin2Converter.dylib 49.0.0 (compatibility 1.0.0) <66210AF5-49B2-3705-5ED3-8326276B1396> /System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libLatin2Converter.dylib
0xffff0000 - 0xffff1fff  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <2DCD13E3-1BD1-6F25-119A-3863A3848B90> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Model: MacBook4,1, BootROM MB41.00C1.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.31f1
Graphics: Intel GMA X3100, GMA X3100, Built-In, 144 MB
Memory Module: global_name
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x88), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.42.4)
Bluetooth: Version 2.4.5f3, 2 service, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: FUJITSU MHY2250BH, 232,89 GB
Parallel ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GSA-S10N
USB Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8501, 0xfd400000 / 7
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub [MTT], 0x1a40  (TERMINUS TECHNOLOGY INC.), 0x0201, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub [MTT], 0x1a40  (TERMINUS TECHNOLOGY INC.), 0x0201, 0xfd150000 / 3
USB Device: 2.4G Receiver, 0x1d57, 0xd2d1, 0xfd155000 / 6
USB Device: 2.4GHZ Mouse, 0x1ea7, 0x0002, 0xfd152000 / 5
USB Device: External HDD, 0x1058  (Western Digital Technologies, Inc.), 0x1003, 0xfd110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8205, 0x1a100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x022a, 0x5d200000 / 3
USB Device: IR Receiver, 0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242, 0x5d100000 / 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system requirements state that you need at least OS X 10.7. According to the crash report, you have 10.6.8.

System requirements: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/installation

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded system to Lion and it works but I was hoping that it could work on 10.6.8.